# how can I resolve the error Dash can not load data in browser (error loading layout)

Tags: python, loading, plotly-dash

Quite some posts have discussed the matter, but nothing to solve my problem. The problem is the 'error loading layout' in the browser when running the multi-page dash app. In the terminal I have no error.

my app is based on the 'towards data science'article: https://towardsdatascience.com/callbacks-layouts-bootstrap-how-to-create-dashboards-in-plotly-dash-1d233ff63e30

I already have re-installed the different modules and have started all over again, all without a satisfying result.

my code is:

app.py

```
import dash

app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
server = app.server
```

index.py

```
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash import Output, Input

from app import app
from layouts import navbar
from layouts import layout_overview, layout_comparison, layout_analysis

app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

app.layout = html.Div([
            dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
            navbar(),
            html.Div(id='page-content')
])


@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
            [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    
    if pathname == '/':
        return layout_overview
    elif pathname == '/overview':
        return layout_overview
    elif pathname == '/comparison':
        return layout_comparison
    elif pathname == '/analysis':
        return layout_analysis
    else:
        return '404'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port='5000', host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

layouts.py (is under construction)

```
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import pandas as pd


########################################
# Add Data
########################################

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\StefanSijbesmaDAAT\\Documents\\Scripting\\Test\\assets\\Life expectancy.csv')
years = df['Year'].unique()
country=df['Entity'].unique()

########################################
# Create Auxiliary Components Here
########################################

def navbar():
    html.Nav([  # navbar on top of the dashboard using html components
        dcc.Link(
            html.H4('Overview'),
            href='/overview',
            style={
                'display': 'inline-block',
                'margin-right': '30px'
                    }
        ),
        dcc.Link(
            html.H4('Comparison'),
            href='/comparison',
            style={
                'display': 'inline-block',
                'margin-right': '30px'
                    }
        ),
        dcc.Link(
            html.H4('Analysis'),
            href='/analysis',
            style={
                'display': 'inline-block',
                'margin-right': '230px'
                    }
        ),
            ], className='navbar'),
    
    return navbar


########################################
# Create Page Layouts Here
########################################

### Layout Overview
layout_overview = html.Div('overview'

)

### Layout Comparison
layout_comparison = html.Div('comparison'

)

### Layout Analysis
layout_analysis = html.Div('analysis'

)
```

callbacks.py

*still empty*

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `navbar()` function. It should return one element, currently you are returning a function (since you forgot to assign the `html.Nav` element to the variable and return it).

Fixed code:

```
def navbar():
    navbar_element = html.Nav(
        [  # navbar on top of the dashboard using html components
            dcc.Link(
                html.H4("Overview"),
                href="/overview",
                style={"display": "inline-block", "margin-right": "30px"},
            ),
            dcc.Link(
                html.H4("Comparison"),
                href="/comparison",
                style={"display": "inline-block", "margin-right": "30px"},
            ),
            dcc.Link(
                html.H4("Analysis"),
                href="/analysis",
                style={"display": "inline-block", "margin-right": "230px"},
            ),
        ],
        className="navbar",
    )

    return navbar_element
```

Also be careful, you have comma after `html.Nav()` definition, that can cause the function `navbar` to return `tuple` instead of one element.

After this fix you won't see the layout when accessing `http://127.0.0.1:5000` since your `display_page` callback require to access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. So that is also part which you can improve.